# Creating vertical dictionary from text file

Tags: python, dictionary

Ok, so I have a text file, first two rows should be skipped, 3rd row, should be keys for dictionary, and then I have around 15,000 entries, I need to create a dictionary with keys mentioned in 3rd row, so it will be a vertical dictionary, parameters are separated by tab (`'\t'`).

I have:

```
Not important, this line should be skipped
Not important, this line should be skipped
Name Surname Telephone Address WebAddress
A1 B1 8484582 fghjkjdjstr www.fghjk.com
A2 B2 8484582 fghjkjdjstr www.fghjk.com
A3 B3 8484582 fghjkjdjstr www.fghjk.com
A4 B4 8484582 fghjkjdjstr www.fghjk.com
A5 B5 8484582 fghjkjdjstr www.fghjk.com
A6 B6 8484582 fghjkjdjstr www.fghjk.com
```

How do I get following output?

```
Dict = {'Name': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6'],
        'Surname': ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6'], 
        'Telephone': ['fghjkjdjstr', 'fghjkjdjstr', 'fghjkjdjstr', 'fghjkjdjstr', 'fghjkjdjstr', 'fghjkjdjstr'],
        'Address': ['fghjkjdjstr', 'fghjkjdjstr', 'fghjkjdjstr', 'fghjkjdjstr', 'fghjkjdjstr', 'fghjkjdjstr'], 
        'WebAddress': ['www.fghjk.com', 'www.fghjk.com', 'www.fghjk.com', 'www.fghjk.com', 'www.fghjk.com', 'www.fghjk.com']}
```

I'm posting my attempt

```
def Reading_Old_File(self, Path):
        Old_Values={}
        with open(Path,'r') as Old_File:
            while line:
                for index, line in enumerate(Old_File, start=1):
                    if index==1:
                        pass
                    if index==2:
                        pass
                    if index==3:
                        indexes=line.split("\t")
                        for index in indexes:
                            Old_Values=Old_Values{[key]} # What here?
                    if index>3:
                        data=line.split("\t")
            print Old_Values
```

As I've mentioned before first two lines have unimportant information, third is supposed to be keys, 4th and next, are values, so I wanted to append values, and keys to dictionary, is that possible?

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? Also, what is your output structure supposed to be; dictionary of lists?

Comment: I have a text file, in the following format, I want to read it, and save in a dictionary, so my output would be as I mentioned

Comment: What is the point of writing code I've written, which simply is not doing what I want? That's what I'm asking for, help, because looks like I can't manage it, so why do you want me instead of clear question, ask something  like mixture of code and problem?

Comment: I'd think of renting if it would not be my personal wish, but anyway, have posted one my attempts, any help now?

Comment: It's helpful to also include precisely what is *wrong* with your attempt, e.g. providing the error traceback, but I've answered anyway.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've done some changes, can you say why it keeps giving me list instead of dictionary?

Comment: Given that all I know it it's *"another way"*... no. If you have a new question, do ask it (but please follow e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: What do you mean *"keeps giving me list"*? Your code doesn't `return` anything, and the empty lists you do create in your dictionary are then replaced (note: not `.append`ed to) on subsequent lines. Please provide expected and actual outputs, for a minimal example of input data, in a **new question**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if index==3:
    indexes=line.split("\t")
    for index in indexes:
         Old_Values=Old_Values{[key]} # What here?
```

As I understand it, what you want there is simply an empty list to put the corresponding elements from the subsequent lines in:

```
Old_Values[index] = []
```

Which will give you:

```
{'WebAddress': [], 'Address': [], 'Surname': [], 'Name': [], 'Telephone': []}
```

I don't know where `key` was coming from, and your function won't start because `while line` happens before `line` is defined (and is redundant anyway). Really, it should look like:

```
def reading_old_file(self, path):
    old_values = {}
    with open(path) as old_file: # 'r' is the default mode
        for index, line in enumerate(old_file, start=1):
            if index == 3: # just leave out pass cases 
                indexes = line.split("\t")
                for index in indexes:
                    old_values[index] = []
            elif index > 3: # use elif for exclusive cases 
                data = line.split("\t")
                ... # use indexes to put elements in appropriate lists
    print old_values # should probably return something, too
```

Note compliance with the [style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Thanks, I've just realised that I can do it another way

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
data = {}
headers = None
for line in open('file.txt'):
    cols = line.strip().split()
    if not headers:
        headers = cols
        continue
    for field, c in zip(headers, col):
        data.setdefault(field, []).append(c)
```